# How to create Eclipse Project via Command Line or similiar solution?

Tags: java

first of all sorry for my bad english. I have a question and I cant find an answer anywhere.
My Programm exports some loose *.java files withouth any entrypoint. The written API allows an CMD to be executed. Problem is, the CMD Order to start eclipse with parameters. My questions is is it possible to start eclipse 3.3-3.6 with a command line parameter to create a project. Creating a Workspace through -data c:\xxxx\myworkspace is no problem but since eclipse sees no files outside a project, i need to make one so i can put my java files into it and startup an remote debug after it. The Plan is to startup an external export java file, which starts eclipse with the defined workspace and a fresh project (with the exported java files) for usage.

Answer (score 1):

Using Maven it's possible to create an Eclipse project and all kinds of useful stuff, http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-ide-eclipse.html gives at least a starting point

Answer (score 0):

There are some tools like Maven or Ant plugins that create Eclipse projects from some structural information (e.g. the Maven plugin reads the pom.xml).

If your code is unstructured it might be hard to create a fully functional Eclipse project. You might be able to create a Java project and define its source path (in fact it's a simple XML file called .project - you could easily write one yourself) but any other information like additional dependencies etc. would have to be added manually.

Besides that, creating a simple project from existing sources isn't that hard in Eclipse. Why don't you just do it manually?